# How to cache all urls like /page/id where id is a number using workbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Given the following code snippet from my nodejs server:

```
 router.get('/page/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
 var id = req.params.id;
 if ( typeof req.params.id === "number"){id = parseInt(id);}
 res.render('page.ejs' , { vara:a , varb:b });
 });
```

I want to do exactly what I'm doing in the nodejs server but on from the service worker.
I've generated & built it using workbox but I don't know how to cache all the urls like /page/1 or /page/2 or .... /page/4353 and so on without overcharging the service worker source code.

The nodejs code from above it's working 100%.
I tried to so something like:

```
.....{
"url": "/page/\*",
"revision": "q8j4t1d072f2g6l5unc0q6c0r7vgs5w0"
},....
```

It doesn't work in the service worker pre-cache when I reloaded the website with this code added into the service worker it was installing and it took pretty much. Is that normal? Can't I do that without overcharging the entire installing process and browser cache memory?

Thank you for help!

EDIT:

My service worker looks like :

```
 importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.2/workbox-sw.js");

 if (workbox) {
   console.log('Workbox status : ONLINE');
 } else {
   console.log('Workbox status : OFFLINE');
 }

 workbox.skipWaiting();
 workbox.clientsClaim();

 self.__precacheManifest = [
   {
     "url": "/",
     "revision": "7e50eec344ce4d01730894ef1d637d4d"
   },
   'head.ejs',
   'navbar.ejs',
   'map_script.ejs',
   'scripts.ejs',
   'details.json',
   'page.ejs',
   'home.ejs',
   'map.ejs',
   'about.ejs',
   {
     "url": "/page",
     "revision": "881d8ca1f2aacfc1617c09e3cf7364f0",
     "cleanUrls": "true"
   },
   {
     "url": "/about",
     "revision": "11d729194a0669e3bbc938351eba5d00"
   },
   {
     "url": "/map",
     "revision": "c3942a2a8ac5b713d63c53616676974a"
   },
   {
     "url": "/getJson",
     "revision": "15c88be34ben24a683f7be97fd8abc4e"
   },
   {
     "url": "/getJson1",
     "revision": "15c88be34bek24a6l3f7be97fd3aoc4e"
   },
   {
     "url": "/getJson2",
     "revision": "15c82be34ben24a683f7be17fd3amc4e"
   },
   {
     "url": "/getJson3",
     "revision": "15c62be94ben24a683f7be17gd3amc4r"
   },
   {
     "url": "/getJson4",
     "revision": "15c62beh4ben24a6g3f7be97gd3amc4p"
   },
   {
     "url": "/public/_processed_/2/7/csm.jpg",
     "revision": "15c62beh4bek44a6g3f7ben7gd3amc4p"
   },
   {
     "url": "/public/_processed_/2/7/csm.jpg",
     "revision": "15c62beh4ben24a6g3f7be9ngd3a2c4p"
   }
 ].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
 workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
 workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Workbox service worker has its own process of caching.

Based from the documentation of [Workbox PreCaching](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching):

> One feature of service workers is the ability to save a set of files
>   to the cache when the service worker is installing. This is often
>   referred to as "**precaching**", since you are caching content ahead of
>   the service worker being used.

The `precacheAndRoute` method sets up an implicit cache-first handler. This is why the home page loaded while we were offline even though we had not written a fetch handler for those files.

> If a request **fails to match the precache**, we'll add `.html` to end to
>   support "clean" URLs (a.k.a "pretty" URLs). This means a request like
>   `/about` will match `/about.html`.
>
> ```
> workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(   
>   [
>     '/styles/index.0c9a31.css',
>     '/scripts/main.0d5770.js',
>     { url: '/index.html', revision: '383676' },   
>   ],   
>     {
>      cleanUrls: true,   
>     } 
> );
> ```

You can try to implement this method of [caching files with service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker#working_with_data):

> **cache.addAll(requests)** - This method is the same as add except it
>   takes an array of URLs and adds them to the cache. If any of the files
>   fail to be added to the cache, the whole operation will fail and none
>   of the files will be added.

For more infos:

- [Workbox-SW](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw)
- [Workbox Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/workbox-lab/#0)

Comment: So do you suggest to add in the precacheAndRoute([]); the *.ejs files and urls both of them thogether?Something like : '/views/page.ejs',{url:'/page'}?

Comment: Just try to follow the format of 'url' based from the documentation. You can also try to add the '.js' and  '.css' if you want. That's only an example on how to do it.

Comment: I tried,but didn't work,the thing is the service worker is not caching the pages with urls like /page/id , id = 0,1,2...

Comment: I cached the pages aswell as .ejs files not as urls

Comment: The page.ejs is cached.But the browser will access it using an url like /page/id
And when I do that with this service worker configuration it displays the page.ejs but it is bugged,it contains no data because there is no variable passed to the server

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the precache is to cache the minimal set of web assets  -that you need to get your page up and running - during service worker installation. It is generally not used to cache a whole bunch of data.

What you probably need is a dynamic cache:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  \/page/g,
  workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'my-cache',
  })
);
```

In this case, the first hit will get the page from the network. Thereafter it will be served from the cache.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for help!Sadly it didn't work so I updated my post and I added the entire code from my service worker hoping you could figure out easier where should be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be that you are expecting clean urls according to the manifest, but you are actually expecting dynamic urls with different params. For that, I suspect you might want to use regex.

An example for caching google fonts:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com/,
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'google-fonts-stylesheets'
  })
);
```

Maybe try something closer to (regex might need some love, I did not verify):

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /\/page\/*/,
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'pages'
  })
);
```

Edit: I realize my answer is the same as @voiceuideveloper but I believe this is the right answer. I do this in my current app and it works well.